# Why does a tag exclusion search find posts containing the text of the tag?

Tags: bug

I was curious as to if I could filter out posts with a particular tag & the result was not what I expected: it appears that give back results don't have that particular tag, but do have the tag's text somewhere in the post. The search results description seems to back this up, E.G when I search on '-[2d]' it says:

> results found containing
>
> "-[2d]"
>
> tagged with
>
> not [2d](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2d)

For clarity, this was using the search box in the upper right corner. When I tried this search directly from the URL, it discard the search request entirely.

Comment: "-2D && -[2d]" will do what you seem to want, but it does seem like any sort of -[tag] query *will* search for the text in brackets unless explicitly disallowed; that's odd.

Comment: Since this isn't GDSE specific, should I ask this on SO meta instead?

Comment: No, it's fine to ask it here, the staff monitor the `bug` tag across all sites.